# Excel Report - Excel Formulas

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to formulate my data on a report in order to return the sum of items from column C based on the same item on column A and column B. For example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FadW7.png (I can't post the image because I don't have 10 reputation yet T.T)

On the above image, User "A" has used a Sum of data for "z1". I need to automatically grab a list of users per zones and sum the data for that user and that zone.

I have elementary experience with Excel (I can add formulas but I do not know what formula to write), any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS($C$1:$C$16,$A$1:$A$16,"a",$B$1:$B$16,"z1")
```

(COLUMN TO SUM, COLUMN WITH 1ST CRITERIA, 1ST CRITERIA, COLUMN WITH 2ND CRITERIA, 2ND CRITERIA)

or

```
=SUMIFS($C$1:$C$16,$A$1:$A$16,G1,$B$1:$B$16,G2)
```

where Cells G1 and G2 are the user and zone respectively.

You'll also need to change the range of the cells in the columns.

Comment: Wow, thank you. That is perfect. The first one works exactly the way I want it to. The 2nd one didn't really work but one more question in regards to that. If I were to automatically create a matrix for each user, so User Name, Zone. Would I use the 1st one and point at a list of users rather than hard inputting "a" and "z1" ?

Comment: Yes, that was what my second example was supposed to do, but you're better off putting the matrix in the two columns previous to the formula. So if your formula is in Col F put the username in D and the zone in E and reference the cells rather than the hard input. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It Does. Thank you very much. You sir have solved my problem :)